# get value from fireBase for complex object that contains List<string>

Tags: android, list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have object that contains List and when I try to get the value back from firebase - database i get an error :"com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.ArrayList to String"

the setValue for this object is without any problem, the data save currently.

This is the set&get method for the list in "warrant" object:

```
public class SearchLocation implements Serializable {
private List<String> custodian;

   public void setCustodian(String custodianUid) {
   if(custodian == null)
       custodian = new ArrayList<>();
   custodian.add(custodianUid);
}

public List<String> getCustodian() {
    return custodian;
}
```

}

this is how I try to get the vale:

```
        DB_Service.getData(evidenceRef, new OnGetDataListener() {
        @Override
       public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         searchLocations = new ArrayList<>();

          for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               SearchLocation searchLocation = snapshot.getValue(SearchLocation.class);
                searchLocation.setUid(snapshot.getKey());
              searchLocations.add(searchLocation);
            }
```

[image]

Comment: add your firebase database structure

Comment: link with the photo as added

Comment: Have you solved he issue? Please responde with @AleMamo

Answer (score 0):

Update your `setCustodian()` method. it's should accept `List<String>` not String .

so you have to update like below

```
 public void setCustodian(List<String> custodian) {
      this.custodian=custodian;
 }
```

I hope it's will solve your issue.